# if else sql with additional information

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

i have a case that the new column in sql contain of additional information, this is example

```
  A  |      B
  2     Increase 2
 -3     Decrease -3
  0     Not changed
 Null   Not changed
```

anyone can help me to solve this B column that use if-else statement, i have tried with this code

```
if(a>0, "increase"+a, "decrease"+a) as B
```

but i get error. anyone can help me please?
thank you in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do?  are you trying to derive an appropriate column B given the column A?

Comment: i just want to give an information in B column that the A column will be deleted after i get the B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this:

```
SELECT decode( a>0, concat('Increase ',a), concat('Decrease ',a ) ) as B
from mytable
```

Comment: i have tried this code, but it return to a column value without the information "decrease" or "increase"

Comment: try with concat.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can use a `case` expression:

```
select a,
       (case when a > 0 then concat('Increase ', a)
             when a < 0 then concat('Decrease ', a)
             else 'Not changed'
        end) as b
from t;
```